# Problems translating strings for my module

Tags: i18n-l10n

As far I as know, the `t()` function is supposed to collect the strings and allow for their translation at `admin/config/regional/translate/translate`. This is not happening though for my module's string. Despite disabling the module + flushing the cache + enabling back, the string does not show up there.

*I'm aware of the filters and case-sensitivity of the search field.*

Any ideas as per what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The string has to be displayed at least once on the site (as far as i know). If this does not work, try to rename the string you want to replace with a translation and clear the caches again.